# How to calculate t-statistic for the difference between two groups using robust standard erros?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to estimate t-statistic for a difference between two groups and I need to use robust standard errors.

I have two groups and I have estimated both groups coefficients' using lm-model. Then I have subtracted second models coefficient from the first ones coefficient. This way I am able to get the difference.

But now I need to calculate t-statistics for the difference using robust standard errors. And this is where the problems start.. I do not know how to calculate these robust standard errors when I have two groups that I would like to compare. I have tried using t.test function in R but I think this is not the right way.

Can you help me where to start?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

With the `lmtest` and `sandwich` packages:

```
# simulates some data
set.seed(666) # just for replication
n1 <- 10; n2 <- 15 # sample sizes
y1 <- rnorm(n1)
y2 <- rnorm(n2)
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), times = c(n1, n2))
dat <- data.frame(group = group, y = c(y1, y2))

# linear regression
fit <- lm(y ~ group, data = dat)

# standard erros, p-values, confidence intervals, based on robust 
#   estimation of the variance-covariance matrix
library(parameters)
standard_error_robust(fit)
p_value_robust(fit)
ci_robust(fit)

# or 
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(fit, vcov = vcovHC)
# t test of coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) -0.096076   0.494739 -0.1942   0.8477
# groupB       0.102826   0.575257  0.1787   0.8597
```

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your help. In my case, I have two different datas. Both datas contain the same information but for different days and the lengths of the datas are not the same. I have estimated the coefficients with two linear regressions and would like to compare whether coefficient from data1 is statistically different from data2's coefficient. I wasn't able to run the regression containing both data sets, since I ended up with large t-statistics. Is it possible to run two separate regressions and still get t-statistics for their difference using robust standard errors?